# How to filter object and display it in React

Tags: reactjs

How to filter the object value from desc based on the main.

Is there any possible way i can get value xyz , qwer , poiu and save into variable. As main contain `1,3,5` so i want to fetch the desc object value xyz , qwer , poiu in Reactjs

```
const data = {
  main: '1,3,5',
  desc: [
    {
      id: '1',
      value: 'xyz'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      value: 'abc'
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      value: 'qwer'
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      value: 'cwer'
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      value: 'poiu'
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried this but it fails

```
export default function App() {
  const res = data.desc.find(d => d.id === data.main)
  console.log(res);

  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
       {res && res.value}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.main` is a string so you should split into an `array`, then filter it by matching it to `data.desc.id`. CodesandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-breeze-6tch6?file=/src/App.js

```js
const data = {
  main: '1,3,5',
  desc: [
    {
      id: '1',
      value: 'xyz'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      value: 'abc'
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      value: 'qwer'
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      value: 'cwer'
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      value: 'poiu'
    }
  ]
}

var filtered = data.desc.filter(e => data.main.split(',').indexOf(e.id) !== -1);
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: what does this line ```.indexOf(e.id) !== -1``` actually mean?

Comment: `var filtered = data.desc.filter(e => data.main.split(',').includes(e.id));`
You could use `includes` for readability if indexOf confuses you.
Use `indexOf` when you want the index of the array.
You could check the [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: `indexOf` is a function of an array to find the index of first occurrence of element, if element is not in the array then it will return `-1` more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: what if mains has only one value there is case when split is not function error will be there    ```  mains: "1"   ```